# How to load and insert some HTML only if the user is human (reCaptcha v3)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fetch, typeerror

## Goal

To protect the web app from malicious spam bot crawlers and similar malicious actors my goal is to use reCAPTCHA v3 to analyze the user visiting the site and if the Captcha v3 score is good enough (let's say 0.5 or better) use the Fetch API to POST the token and so verify it and if the score is good enough as mentioned previously return the E-Mail address within some HTML. For simplicity sake, the `function loadContactbubble()` gets executed when you click a button.

## Problems

- I am not sure where to implement the `if (response.score => 0.5)` check.
- Frontend semi-works in that regard that in the network browser debug tools it gives an response but in the console it prints out the response as `undefined`
- Is my implementation secure enough? Can't the secret key somehow siphoned or similar?
- I get a lot of CSP warnings in the browser, might this be an issue in production?

## Code

I was following this guide: https://dev.to/spencer741/google-recaptcha-v3-server-side-validation-using-asp-net-core-5-0-3hfb (that means that the code is like 80-90% from this article)

My appsettings.json contains the secret key and the siteverify Link (API link).

GHttpModels.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace _projectname.Tooling
    {

        public class GRequestModel
        {
            public string path { get; set; }
            public string secret { get; set; }
            public string response { get; set; }
            public string remoteip { get; set; }

            public GRequestModel(string res, string remip)
            {
                response = res;
                remoteip = remip;
                secret = Startup.Configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:Secret"];
                path = Startup.Configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:ApiUrl"];
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                {
                    //Invoke logger
                    throw new Exception("Invalid 'Secret' or 'Path' properties in appsettings.json. Parent: GoogleRecaptchaV3.");
                }
            }
        }

        //Google's response property naming is 
        //embarrassingly inconsistent, that's why we have to 
        //use DataContract and DataMember attributes,
        //so we can bind the class from properties that have 
        //naming where a C# variable by that name would be
        //against the language specifications... (i.e., '-').
        [DataContract]
        public class GResponseModel
        {
            [DataMember]
            public bool success { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string challenge_ts { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string hostname { get; set; }

            //Could create a child object for 
            //error-codes
            [DataMember(Name = "error-codes")]
            public string[] error_codes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

GoogleReCaptchaV3Service.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

    namespace _projectname.Tooling
    {
        public class CaptchaRequestException : Exception
        {
            public CaptchaRequestException()
            {
            }
            public CaptchaRequestException(string message)
                : base(message)
            {
            }
            public CaptchaRequestException(string message, Exception inner)
                : base(message, inner)
            {
            }
        }

        public interface IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service
        {
            HttpClient _httpClient { get; set; }
            GRequestModel Request { get; set; }
            GResponseModel Response { get; set; }
            void InitializeRequest(GRequestModel request);
            Task<bool> Execute();
        }

        public class GoogleRecaptchaV3Service : IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service
        {
            public HttpClient _httpClient { get; set; }

            public GRequestModel Request { get; set; }

            public GResponseModel Response { get; set; }

            public HttpRequestException HttpReqException { get; set; }

            public Exception GeneralException { get; set; }

            public GoogleRecaptchaV3Service(HttpClient httpClient)
            {
                _httpClient = httpClient;
            }

            public void InitializeRequest(GRequestModel request)
            {
                Request = request;
            }

            public async Task<bool> Execute()
            {
                // Notes on error handling:
                // Google will pass back a 200 Status Ok response if no network or server errors occur.
                // If there are errors in on the "business" level, they will be coded in an array;
                // CaptchaRequestException is for these types of errors.

                // CaptchaRequestException and multiple catches are used to help seperate the concerns of 
                //  a) an HttpRequest 400+ status code 
                //  b) an error at the "business" level 
                //  c) an unpredicted error that can only be handled generically.

                // It might be worthwhile to implement a "user error message" property in this class so the
                // calling procedure can decide what, if anything besides a server error, to return to the 
                // client and any client handling from there on.
                try
                {

                    //Don't to forget to invoke any loggers in the logic below.

                    //formulate request
                    string builtURL = Request.path + '?' + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode($"secret={Request.secret}&response={Request.response}&remoteip={Request.remoteip}");
                    StringContent content = new StringContent(builtURL);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Sent Request {builtURL}");

                    //send request, await.
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(builtURL, null);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    //read response
                    byte[] res = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

                    string logres = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved Response: {logres}");

                    //Serialize into GReponse type
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(res))
                    {
                        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GResponseModel));
                        Response = (GResponseModel)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
                    }

                    //check if business success
                    if (!Response.success)
                    {
                        throw new CaptchaRequestException();
                    }

                    //return bool.
                    return true; //response.IsSuccessStatusCode; <- don't need this. EnsureSuccessStatusCode is now in play.
                }            
                catch (HttpRequestException hre)
                {
                    //handle http error code.
                    HttpReqException = hre;

                    //invoke logger accordingly

                    //only returning bool. It is ultimately up to the calling procedure
                    //to decide what data it wants from the Service.
                    return false;
                }
                catch (CaptchaRequestException ex)
                {

                    //Business-level error... values are accessible in error-codes array.
                    //this catch block mainly serves for logging purposes. 

                    /*  Here are the possible "business" level codes:
                        missing-input-secret    The secret parameter is missing.
                        invalid-input-secret    The secret parameter is invalid or malformed.
                        missing-input-response  The response parameter is missing.
                        invalid-input-response  The response parameter is invalid or malformed.
                        bad-request             The request is invalid or malformed.
                        timeout-or-duplicate    The response is no longer valid: either is too old or has been used previously.
                    */

                    //invoke logger accordingly 

                    //only returning bool. It is ultimately up to the calling procedure 
                    //to decide what data it wants from the Service.
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Generic unpredictable error
                    GeneralException = ex;

                    // invoke logger accordingly

                    //only returning bool. It is ultimately up to the calling procedure 
                    //to decide what data it wants from the Service.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
//from captchav3
using _projectname.Tooling;

namespace _projectname
{
    public class CookieCheckMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CookieCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.Cookies["ModalShown"] == null && httpContext.Request.Path != "/Cookies")
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/Cookies?q="+ httpContext.Request.Path);
            }
            await _next(httpContext); // calling next middleware

        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class CookieCheckMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCookieCheckMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CookieCheckMiddleware>();
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        internal static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        //public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Captcha v3
            services.AddHttpClient<IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service, GoogleRecaptchaV3Service>();
            services.AddTransient<IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service, GoogleRecaptchaV3Service>();
            services.AddControllers();
            //Register dependencies
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                //app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
                //{
                //    await next();

                //    if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.Response.HasStarted)
                //    {
                //        //Re-execute the request so the user gets the error page
                //        string originalPath = ctx.Request.Path.Value;
                //        ctx.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
                //        ctx.Request.Path = "/Cloud";
                //        await next();
                //    }
                //});
                // orig
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Errors/{0}");
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
    

            app.UseRouting();
            // TEST
            app.UseCookieCheckMiddleware();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            };
            app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                // Experimental
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<button onclick="loadContactbubble();">Load contacts</button>
```

site.js (only the function for brevity):

```
function loadContactbubble() {
    grecaptcha.execute('sitekeyhere', { action: 'onclick' }).then(function (token) {
        console.log(token);
        fetch("/load/contactbubble?RecaptchaToken=" + token, {
            method: "POST",
            body: token,
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorBuild = {
                type: "Error",
                message: response.message || "Something went wrong",
                data: response.data || "",
                code: response.code || "",
            };
        }
    }
        //addText("Error: " + JSON.stringify(errorBuild));
        //toggleLoader(2, "hidden");
        //return;
    )
}
```

ApiController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using _projectname.Tooling;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _projectname.Controllers
{
    public class SignUpModel
    {
        public string RecaptchaToken { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("load/contactbubble")]
    public class SignUp : ControllerBase
    {
        IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service _gService { get; set; }
        public SignUp(IGoogleRecaptchaV3Service gService)
        {
            _gService = gService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromQuery] SignUpModel SignUpData)
        {

            GRequestModel rm = new GRequestModel(SignUpData.RecaptchaToken,
                                                 HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString());

            _gService.InitializeRequest(rm);

            if (!await _gService.Execute())
            {
                //return error codes string.
                return Ok(_gService.Response.error_codes);
            }

            //call Business layer

            //return result
            return base.Content("<div>Welcome human! Here is our secret e-mail: test@test.com</div>", "text/html");

        }
    }
}
```

## Errors

If I click the button the following gets printed out in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "ok", response is undefined
```

The response contains proper HTML in the network tab, which is weird.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your function

```
function (token) {
    console.log(token);
    fetch("/load/contactbubble?RecaptchaToken=" + token, {
        method: "POST",
        body: token,
    });
}
```

does not return anything, hence why the argument passed to the next `.then((response) => ...` is *undefined*.

Make this function return the fetched data, and it should hopefully work:

```
function (token) {
    console.log(token);

    return fetch("/load/contactbubble?RecaptchaToken=" + token, {
        method: "POST",
        body: token
    });
}
```

(Well, it should then at least forward the fetch result to the next `.then((response) => ...`. I have not looked for other errors in your code, so "*it should hopefully work*" is to be understood with respect to the one problem i explained here...)

Comment: Welcome to the community :-) It seems that adding return returns the response in some weird format, meaning that the `.then((response) =>`... doesn't work for some reason :-(

Comment: Nevermind, the response.ok works completely fine, now how do I append the HTML content? I only see four response types and text is not what I want in order to append HTML into the page..